# How to create material design like custom scrollbar with numbers and alphabets bubble in recyclerview

Tags: android, material-design

In many new android applications and their latest update those applications(mostly material design) have a custom scrollbar with letters and numbers, while scrolling the scrollbar with thumb, alphabets or numbers appear beside thumb.I have attached screenshot to the question of the scrollbar from the application 'Contacts'.

Screenshot:
[image]

So, How to modify a scrollbar in my application which is using recyclerview, to create scrollbar like that scrollbar with the alphabet and number bubble or is there any new API or library introduced for that?

Comment: Good question :D :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For anyone still looking for an answer for this. I have found a number of libraries which provide this functionality:

1. https://github.com/krimin-killr21/MaterialScrollBar
2. https://github.com/plusCubed/recycler-fast-scroll
3. https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller
4. https://github.com/timusus/RecyclerView-FastScroll

All of the above provide FastScroll mechanism (what you're looking for) - though some look nicer than others.

I have found the [MaterialScrollBar](https://github.com/krimin-killr21/MaterialScrollBar) easiest to get set with up and use, as well as the fact that it has the nicest cosmetics (adheres to material design guidelines and looks just like Contacts app).

This library is also actively maintained and developed, issues & PR's being closed etc.

Hope this may help someone as I spent a lot of time looking for this myself.

Answer (score 4):

**I use this new one now -
https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll**

Below is my previous one.

I have used fastscroller by FutureMind in **Android Studio**

https://github.com/FutureMind/recycler-fast-scroll

**Usage**

**1) Compile required dependency by adding**

compile 'com.futuremind.recyclerfastscroll:fastscroll:0.2.4'

**2) Edit Layout File to add FastScroller**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.futuremind.recyclerviewfastscroll.FastScroller
        android:id="@+id/fastscroll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**3) In Activity/Fragment associate fastScroller with your recycler view**

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    fastScroller = (FastScroller) findViewById(R.id.fastscroll);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //has to be called AFTER RecyclerView.setAdapter()
    fastScroller.setRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

**4) In your RecyclerView.Adapter implement SectionTitleProvider to display the content on Bubble**

```
    public class MyAdapter ... implements SectionTitleProvider{

        ...

        @Override
        public String getSectionTitle(int position) {
            //this String will be shown in a bubble for specified position
            return getItem(position).substring(0, 1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[List View Variants](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants) library seems to be perfect for your needs, try it out.

Check out the demo below.

[image: The demo of the library]

Answer (score 0):

This library works fine and it is easy to use - [Material Scroll Bar](https://github.com/turing-tech/MaterialScrollBar)

It has also support for custom font.