# Fast scrollbar with alphabet bubble in list View

Tags: java, android, scrollbar

I've a list view in my app. I want to implement fast scrollbar with alphabet suggestion in small bubble. For example:

[image]

I found the same for recycler view [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261437/how-to-create-material-design-like-custom-scrollbar-with-numbers-and-alphabets-b)

I found a third party library for list view but don't know how to implement it in my project. Because there is no description for its use. Can anyone please suggest any alternative or mention steps to use [this](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants) library in my project?

Thanks

Comment: What about SuperSlim? I mean this [link](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM)

Comment: @MohammadZ I think this is also for recycler view see this https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/wiki/Getting%20started%20with%20version%200.4

Answer (score 0):

As in example said, first of all, you must declare your view in XML:

```
<lb.library.PinnedHeaderListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0px"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    tools:listitem="@layout/listview_item"/>
```

`listitem` is layout of your single item.

After that in your activity,

```
private PinnedHeaderListView mListView;
mListView = (PinnedHeaderListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
int pinnedHeaderBackgroundColor = getResources().getColor(getResIdFromAttribute(this, android.R.attr.colorBackground));
mAdapter.setPinnedHeaderBackgroundColor(pinnedHeaderBackgroundColor);
mAdapter.setPinnedHeaderTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pinned_header_text));
mListView.setPinnedHeaderView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pinned_header_listview_side_header, mListView, false));
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mListView.setOnScrollListener(mAdapter);
mListView.setEnableHeaderTransparencyChanges(false);
//    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(mQueryText,new FilterListener() ...
//You can also perform operations on selected item by using :
//    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() ...
```

Note that your adapter must extends `SearchablePinnedHeaderListViewAdapter<T>`